# Password comparaison

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have big problem with my code. In registration, I compare my passowrd and he display password don't match. This is code

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'auth/postregister', 'class' => 'horizontal-form', 'id' => 'formRegister', 'method' => 'POST')) !!}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
                <label>Email</label>
                {!! Form::text('u_email', null, array('placeholder' => 'youremail@domaine.com', 'class' => 'form-group', 'id' => 'u_email', 'required')) !!}
                <label>Mot de passe</label>
                {!! Form::password('pwd1', null, array('placeholder' => '********', 'class' => 'form-group', 'id' => 'pwd1', 'required')) !!}

                <label>Confirmer votre mot de passe</label>
                {!! Form::password('pwd2', null, array('placeholder' => '********', 'class' => 'form-group', 'id' => 'pwd2', 'required')) !!}
                <p id="message"></p>

                <button type="submit" id="subscribe" class="btn btn-danger">S'enregistrer</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#formRegister").validate({
  rules: {
    pwd1: "required",
    pwd2: {
      equalTo: "#pwd1"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

In password confirm the input is red and post data don't pass.
Have you an idea

Comment: "I compare my passowrd and he display password" what does that mean?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-same. So use `pwd2: same:pwd1`

Comment: @lagbox I compare two field password and display in view " password don't match"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extends the jQuery validator to add your rule like this :

```
<script>

    jQuery.validator.addMethod( 'passwordMatch', function(value, element) {

        // The two password inputs
        var password = $("#pwd1").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#pwd2").val();

        // Check for equality with the password inputs
        if (password != confirmPassword ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }, "Your Passwords Must Match");

    $("#formRegister").validate({
        rules: {
            pwd1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            pwd2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                passwordMatch: true // the added rule
            }
        },

        // If you want some custome messages :)
        messages: {
            pwd1: {
                required: "What is your password?",
                minlength: "Your password must contain more than 5 characters"
            },
            pwd2: {
                required: "You must confirm your password",
                minlength: "Your password must contain more than 5 characters",
                passwordMatch: "Your Passwords Must Match" // custom message for mismatched passwords
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Ps : [source](https://gist.github.com/grayghostvisuals/6984561)

Comment: the problem doesn't javascript. I changed password with type text and this is same password but with input type password, the same problem. Have you an idea

Comment: passwordMatch don't solved. I use your code but not resolved.  
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined. Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'passwordMatch' method.